# Trying to access courses.students.list for Google Classroom API

Tags: google-oauth, google-classroom

I am trying to access the [student list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list) for Google Classroom.

I have successfully obtained my OAUTH2 token, I have requested the following scopes:

- userinfo.email
- userinfo.profile
- classroom.profile.emails
- classroom.courses.readonly
- classroom.coursework.me
- classroom.coursework.students

Every time that I try to retrieve the class list I am getting a 403 Permission denied and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Two things to mention: Here is a screenshot showing the permissions I have granted:

[image]

And, interestingly, even after having added the permissions, on the `google project` page where it lists the number of users using sensitive scopes - it is listed as zero (which is odd, I'd have thought it should be 1)

[image]

Any pointers would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not a very satisfactory answer, but, if I add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly` scope, *then* it allows me access *and* returns the email addresses at the same time (when calling the `v1/courses/{courseId}/students` endpoint)

If however you *only have the rosters* scope, then you *can still access* the `v1/courses/{courseId}/students` endpoint, but, you just don't get the email addresses returned.

Quite confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

`/api/v1/courses/:course_id/students` is deprecated.

Instead use:
`/api/v1/courses/:course_id/users?enrollment_type[]=student`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34373623)